# Simulations and floating point error?

Tags: computational-mathematics, simulation, floating-point, error-propagation

Dear math stack exchange,

I'm curious about what would floating point error would look as i've been hoping to conduct some simulations of gravitational phenomenon. Is it highly random or somewhat predictable? Is there a way given certain partial differential equations and the data from a simulation that you could get a gauge for how much error had been accumulated?

Sincerely, a college freshman going on sophomore year

Comment: I suspect you will have to deal with other error terms that are much larger than the floating-point error. Whole books are written about numerical solution of differential equations, which is what you seem to be concerned with.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad in scope to be able to answer.

Comment: What kind of gravitational phenomena? Is it particle physics like planetary systems in Newton mechanics, slight general relativity like gravitational lenses or full relativity like black holes or other solutions of the Einstein gravity equations?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, I do not have the prerequisite knowledge to handle either fully general relativistic phenomenon nor numerically simplified models. I'm trying to consider both Newtonian gravitation as well as other non-standard models but with retarded potentials. Basically a classical representation of gravitation with a finite speed of propagation for changes in the gravitational potential.